# How to reduce the space between button ,here`s my code

Tags: flutter, button

```
           Container(
              child: SizedBox(
                height: 400,
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 1,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 0,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 2,
                  childAspectRatio: 1.5,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Press Me"),
                          onPressed: (){},
                          color: Colors.blue[300],
                          splashColor: Colors.red,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 100.0),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      child: RaisedButton(
                          child: Text("Press Me"),
                          onPressed: (){},
                          color: Colors.blue[300],
                          splashColor: Colors.red,
                          shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0))
                      ),
                      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0,vertical: 100.0),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

[image]

Comment: Please pose a proper question using the ``` code tags...

Comment: why did you use Gridview?

Answer (score 0):

I would use a Column instead of a `GridView`:

```dart
Column(children:[
  RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Press Me')),
  SizedBox(height: 16); // this can be the space between the buttons
  RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('Press Me')),
]);
```

Comment: its not just one button ,its has many in same manner i.e. it keeps on scrolling down

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use a `Column` widget rather than a `GridView.count` if you want to place its children in a vertical order like this.

```
Column(
  children: [
    RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Press Me"),
      onPressed: () {},
      color: Colors.blue[300],
      splashColor: Colors.red,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
    SizedBox(height: 20), //any height you want
    RaisedButton(
      child: Text("Press Me"),
      onPressed: () {},
      color: Colors.blue[300],
      splashColor: Colors.red,
      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

`GridView` should be used when you want to show your widgets in a grid

for more info you can visit [GridView](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GridView-class.html) for `GridView` and [Column](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html) for `Column`

Comment: there are more than two buttons and that too scrollable

Comment: If the items are scrollable you could add a `ListView` or a `ListVew.builder` instead of a `Column` to create a scrollable list